# Not able to split the string based on regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split a string based on the value that is after `:` using RegEx pattern.

I was expecting the result to be something like

```
[
  "hello",
  "js is fun!",
  ""
]
```

Could anyone please help?

**Excerpt from my code**

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:'
const result = str.match(/:[a-z]*/g);
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve the result you described from your input, you should [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) against this regex:

```
(?<=:)\D*
```

which uses a lookbehind to assert that the previous character was a colon (`:`) and then captures all characters until the next digit (or end of string).

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:'
const result = str.match(/(?<=:)\D*/g);
console.log(result)
```

To capture both parts (before and after the colon), you could use [`matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:'
const result = [...str.matchAll(/([\d,]+):(\D*)/g)].map(a => a.slice(1));
console.log(result)
```

If the text after the colon can also include digits you need a more complex regex, using a forward lookahead in the second group to stop matching at either a `\d,\d,\d` pattern or end-of-line:

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:1,0,2:22'
const result = [...str.matchAll(/(\d+,\d+,\d+):(.*?(?=\d+,\d+,\d+|$))/g)].map(a => a.slice(1));
console.log(result)
```

Comment: That is great! Is there a way I can create a pair using that regex?
`[0,0,5, "hello"]`. I tried using `split` but that does not seem to work.

Comment: @scriobh please see my edit, you can do that with `String.matchAll`

Comment: Real quick! How to include digits from this string `'0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:1,0,2:22'`

Comment: @scriobh not real quick - quite a bit more complicated! this might do what you want? `const result = [...str.matchAll(/(\d+,\d+,\d+):(.*?(?=\d+,\d+,\d+|$))/g)].map(a => a.slice(1));`

Comment: Yes, it is. :( Looks like the last one gives `["110,2,2", "22"]`, it should be `["1,0,2", "22"]` instead.

Comment: @scriobh are all the digit strings just single digits?

Comment: No, there can be double digits too, like `["2,20,2", "11"]`

Comment: @scriobh that works for me: https://regex101.com/r/vh4avD/1

Comment: @scriobh also see the new snippet in my answer

Answer (score 2):

The pattern that you tried does not match because the character class does not contain a space, and the `:` will be part of the match. You could turn it into a capture group using `:([a-z\s]*)`

Another option is using a capture group using [matchAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) matching the `:` and capture optional non digits `(\D*)` in group 1.

```js
const str = "0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:";
let result = Array.from(str.matchAll(/:(\D*)/g), m => m[1]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:1,0,2:22';
const rx = /(\d+(?:,\d+){2}):([^:]*?)(?=\d+(?:,\d+){2}:|$)/g;
console.log(Array.from(str.matchAll(rx), x=>[x[1], x[2]]));
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/sPp71C/3).

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^:]*?                   any character except: ':' (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (2 times):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ){2}                     end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $                        before an optional \n, and the end of
                             the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

Comment: How to include digits with this RegEx?

Comment: @scriobh By not excluding them, `/:([^:]*)/g`

Comment: The pattern does not seem to work for this string :( `'0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:1,0,2:22'`

Comment: @scriobh What results do you expect?

Comment: `[
  "hello",
  "js is fun!",
  "",
  "22"
]`

Comment: @scriobh Use `str.match(/:[^:]*?(?=\d+,\d+,\d+:|$)/g).map(x => x.slice(1))`

Comment: Wow! That is great. The pattern did work.

Answer (score 0):

A slight improvement over @Nick's answer, is just to include spaces in the character class:

```js
const str = '0,0,5:hello0,1,5:js is fun!0,2,0:'
const result = str.match(/(?<=:)[a-z ]*/g)
console.log(result)
```